# Optimize Insert statement

Tags: oracle, optimization

I have an insert block which inserts almost 5680969 rows and takes about 10 mins to execute. I tried to optimize using parallel hints and other things like summarizing queries. Can this block of query can be further optimized?? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
DECLARE
        vblQueryName VARCHAR2(20);
    BEGIN
        vblQueryName:='060_745_085';
        INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO TABLE_A
        (
            SOURCE,
            SN,
            CLMNUM,
            CLAIMLINENUMBER,
            CLMTYPE,
            CLMTYPEDESC,
            CLMCATEGORY,
            MEMID,
            ENRID,
            RELFLAG,
            MEMFIRSTNAME,
            MEMLASTNAME,
            GENDER,
            DOB,
            ADDR1,
            ADDR2,
            CITY,
            STATE,
            ZIP,
            HOMEPHONE,
            WORKPHONE,
            LVLID1,
            LVLDESC1,
            LVLID2,
            LVLDESC2,
            LVLID3,
            LVLDESC3,
            LVLID4,
            LVLDESC4,
            LVLID5,
            LVLDESC5,
            LVLID6,
            LVLDESC6,
            LVLID7,
            LVLDESC7,
            LVLID8,
            LVLDESC8,
            LVLID9,
            LVLDESC9,
            LVLID10,
            LVLDESC10,
            FROMDATE,
            TODATE,
            SERVICEDATE,
            RCVDATE,
            PAIDDATE,
            BILLTYPE,
            POSCODE,
            POSDESC,
            SPECCODE,
            SPECDESC,
            DIAGCODE,
            DIAGDESC,
            FIRSTDIAGCODE,
            FIRSTDIAGDESC,
            SECONDDIAGCODE,
            SECONDDIAGDESC,
            THIRDDIAGCODE,
            THIRDDIAGDESC,
            FOURTHDIAGCODE,
            FOURTHDIAGDESC,
            FIFTHDIAGCODE,
            FIFTHDIAGDESC,
            SIXTHDIAGCODE,
            SIXTHDIAGDESC,
            SEVENTHDIAGCODE,
            SEVENTHDIAGDESC,
            EIGHTHDIAGCODE,
            EIGHTHDIAGDESC,
            NINTHDIAGCODE,
            NINTHDIAGDESC,
            TENTHDIAGCODE,
            TENTHDIAGDESC,
            PROCTYPE,
            PROCCODE,
            PROCDESC,
            REVCODE,
            DRGCODE,
            MODIFIERCODE,
            MODIFIERDESC,
            CPT4_1,
            CPT4_2,
            CPT4_3,
            HCPCS,
            CPTII,
            MODIFIERCODE2,
            REVCODE1,
            REVCODE2,
            REVCODE4,
            REVCODE3,
            REVCODE5,
            ICD9PROCCODE1,
            ICD9PROCCODE2,
            ICD9PROCCODE3,
            ICD9PROCCODE4,
            ICD9PROCCODE5,
            ICD9PROCCODE6,
            DRGTYPE,
            DRGIDENTIFIER,
            IPDAYS,
            DISCHSTATUS,
            TYPEOFBILL,
            CLAIMSTATUS,
            ADJCODE,
            PROVID,
            PROVNAME,
            PROVIDERFIRSTNAME,
            PROVIDERLASTNAME,
            PROVNPI,
            PROVZIPCODE,
            SERVTYPECODE,
            SERVTYPEDESC,
            PROVTYPECODE,
            PROVTYPEDESC,
            SERVICECODE,
            SPECROLLUPCODE,
            SPECROLLUPDESC,
            NWKID,
            NWKNAME,
            INNWK,
            NETWORKTYPE,
            SERVICEUNITS,
            PAIDAMT,
            BILLEDAMT,
            ALLOWEDAMT,
            PPOSAVINGAMT,
            ENRPAIDAMT,
            COINSAMT,
            COPAYAMT,
            DEDUCTAMT,
            NOTALLOWEDAMT,
            COBAMT,
            PLANEXCLAMT,
            LABTESTDATA,
            SICCODE,
            SICDESC,
            SSN,
            RCVMTH,
            SRCFILENAME,
            UDF1,
            UDFC10,
            UDFc19,
            UDFc20,
            ICDTYPE,
            VHPAYORID
        )
        SELECT /*+PARALLEL(a,8) */
            'SOURCE' AS SOURCE,
            ROWNUM  AS SN,
            CASE UPPER(a.PROVIDER_NETWORK_PAR_INDICATOR) WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Y_' ELSE 'N_' END || a.CLAIM_NUMBER || a.CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER || ROWNUM AS CLMNUM,
            a.CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER AS CLAIMLINENUMBER,
            'MED' AS CLMTYPE,
            'MEDICAL' AS  CLMTYPEDESC ,
            NULL AS CLMCATEGORY,
            a.MEMID AS MEMID,
            a.SUBSCRIBER_NUMBER AS ENRID,
            NULL AS RELFLAG ,
            UPPER(a.MEMBER_FIRST_NAME) AS MEMFIRSTNAME,
            UPPER(a.MEMBER_LAST_NAME) AS MEMLASTNAME,
            UPPER(a.MEMBER_GENDER) AS GENDER,
            a.MEMBER_DATE_OF_BIRTH AS DOB,
            a.MEMBER_ADDRESS_1 AS ADDR1,
            a.MEMBER_ADDRESS_2 AS ADDR2,
            a.MEMBER_CITY AS CITY,
            a.MEMBER_STATE AS STATE,
            a.MEMBER_ZIP AS ZIP,
            a.MEMBER_PHONE AS HOMEPHONE,
            NULL AS WORKPHONE,
            'SOURCE' AS LVLID1,
            'SOURCE' AS LVLDESC1,
            NULL AS LVLID2,
            NULL AS LVLDESC2,
            NVL(lvl.VRSK_EMPLR_GRPID, REGEXP_REPLACE(a.subgroup_number,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')) AS LVLID3,
            NVL(lvl.EMPLOYER_GROUP_NM, REGEXP_REPLACE(a.subgroup_number,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')) AS LVLDESC3,

            NULL AS LVLID4,
            NULL AS LVLDESC4,
            NULL AS LVLID5,
            NULL AS LVLDESC5,
            NULL AS LVLID6,
            NULL AS LVLDESC6,
            NULL AS LVLID7,
            NULL AS LVLDESC7,
            NULL AS LVLID8,
            NULL AS LVLDESC8,
            NULL AS LVLID9,
            NULL AS LVLDESC9,
            NULL AS LVLID10,
            NULL AS LVLDESC10,
            a.SERVICE_START_DATE AS FROMDATE,
            a.SERVICE_END_DATE AS TODATE,
            a.SERVICE_START_DATE AS SERVICEDATE,
            a.CLAIM_RECEIVED_DATE AS RCVDATE,
            a.CLAIM_PROCESS_DATE AS PAIDDATE,
            Decode(a.ENCOUNTER_TYPE_CODE, 'FCLTY', 'F', 'PROF', 'P', 'DENT', 'P') AS BILLTYPE,
            a.PLACE_OF_SERVICE_CODE AS POSCODE,
            NULL AS POSDESC,
            e.ROLLUP_SPECCODE AS SPECCODE,
            e.ROLLUP_SPECDESC AS SPECDESC,
            COALESCE(a.PRIMARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_2,a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_3,a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_4,a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_5) AS DIAGCODE,
            NULL AS DIAGDESC,
            a.PRIMARY_DIAGNOSIS_CODE AS FIRSTDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS FIRSTDIAGDESC,
            a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_2 AS SECONDDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS SECONDDIAGDESC,
            a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_3 AS THIRDDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS THIRDDIAGDESC,
            a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_4 AS FOURTHDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS FOURTHDIAGDESC,
            a.DIAGNOSIS_CODE_5 AS FIFTHDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS FIFTHDIAGDESC,
            NULL AS SIXTHDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS SIXTHDIAGDESC,
            NULL AS SEVENTHDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS SEVENTHDIAGDESC,
            NULL AS EIGHTHDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS EIGHTHDIAGDESC,
            NULL AS NINTHDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS NINTHDIAGDESC,
            NULL AS TENTHDIAGCODE,
            NULL AS TENTHDIAGDESC,
            NULL AS PROCTYPE,
            COALESCE(proc1.PROCCODE, proc2.PROCCODE, proc3.PROCCODE,a.PROCEDURE_CODE, NULLIF('I'||a.ICD_PROCEDURE_CODE_1,'I'), NULLIF('D'||a.AP_DRG,'D')) AS PROCCODE,
            NULL AS PROCDESC,
            CASE WHEN proc2.procTypeDesc='Rev Code' THEN proc2.PROCCODE END AS REVCODE,
            proc3.PROCCODE AS DRGCODE,
            NULL AS MODIFIERCODE,
            NULL AS MODIFIERDESC,
            CASE WHEN proc2.procTypeDesc='CPT4' THEN proc2.PROCCODE END  AS CPT4_1,
            NULL AS CPT4_2,
            NULL AS CPT4_3,
            CASE WHEN proc2.procTypeDesc='HCPCS' THEN proc2.PROCCODE END  AS HCPCS,
            NULL AS CPTII,
            NULL AS MODIFIERCODE2,
            CASE WHEN proc2.procTypeDesc='Rev Code' THEN proc2.PROCCODE END  AS REVCODE1,
            NULL AS REVCODE2,
            NULL AS REVCODE4,
            NULL AS REVCODE3,
            NULL AS REVCODE5,
            proc1.PROCCODE AS ICD9PROCCODE1,
            REPLACE(a.ICD_PROCEDURE_CODE_2, '.') AS ICD9PROCCODE2,
            REPLACE(a.ICD_PROCEDURE_CODE_3, '.') AS ICD9PROCCODE3,
            NULL AS ICD9PROCCODE4,
            NULL AS ICD9PROCCODE5,
            NULL AS ICD9PROCCODE6,
            NULL AS DRGTYPE,
            NULL AS DRGIDENTIFIER,
            NULL AS IPDAYS,
            a.DISCHARGE_STATUS_CODE AS DISCHSTATUS,
            NULL AS TYPEOFBILL,
            NULL AS CLAIMSTATUS,
            NULL AS ADJCODE,
            coalesce(prov.rollupproviderid, a.provider_number) AS PROVID,
            coalesce(prov.rollupprovidername,a.provider_name) AS PROVNAME,
            NULL AS PROVIDERFIRSTNAME,
            NULL AS PROVIDERLASTNAME,
            NULL AS PROVNPI,
            SubStr(a.PROVIDER_ZIP, 1, 5) AS PROVZIPCODE,
            NULL AS SERVTYPECODE,
            NULL AS SERVTYPEDESC,
            NULL AS PROVTYPECODE,
            NULL AS PROVTYPEDESC,
            NULL AS SERVICECODE,
            NULL AS SPECROLLUPCODE,
            NULL AS SPECROLLUPDESC,
            NVL(d.ROLLUPNWKID,a.PROVIDER_REGION_CODE) AS NWKID,
            COALESCE(d.ROLLUPNWKNAME,a.PROVIDER_REGION_CODE) AS NWKNAME,
            CASE UPPER(a.PROVIDER_NETWORK_PAR_INDICATOR) WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS INNWK,
            NULL AS NETWORKTYPE,
            a.SERVICE_UNIT_COUNT AS SERVICEUNITS,
            Nvl(a.PAID_AMOUNT,0) AS PAIDAMT,
            Nvl(a.CHARGED_AMOUNT,0) AS BILLEDAMT,
            Nvl(a.CHARGED_AMOUNT *0.54,0) AS ALLOWEDAMT, 
            NULL AS PPOSAVINGAMT,
            NVL(a.COPAY_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(a.COINSURANCE_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(a.DEDUCTIBLE_AMOUNT,0) AS ENRPAIDAMT, -- corrected on  /5/30/2013
            Nvl(a.COINSURANCE_AMOUNT,0) AS COINSAMT,
            Nvl(a.COPAY_AMOUNT,0) AS COPAYAMT,
            Nvl(a.DEDUCTIBLE_AMOUNT,0) AS DEDUCTAMT,
            Nvl(a.NOT_COVERED_AMOUNT,0) AS NOTALLOWEDAMT,
            Nvl(a.COB_AMOUNT,0) AS COBAMT,
            NULL AS PLANEXCLAMT,
            NULL AS LABTESTDATA,
            NULL AS SICCODE,
            NULL AS SICDESC,
            NULL AS SSN,
            a.RECEIVEDMONTH AS RCVMTH,
            a.SOURCEFILENAME AS SRCFILENAME,
            'BCBSNC' AS UDF1 ,
            a.SUBSCRIBER_NUMBER|| TO_CHAR(a.MEMBER_DATE_OF_BIRTH,'YYYYMMDD') AS UDFC10,--ICE176721
            a.subgroup_number AS UDFc19,
            a.benefit_package_id AS UDFc20,
            CASE WHEN a.SERVICE_START_DATE>=to_date('20151001','YYYYMMDD') THEN 'ICD10' else 'ICD9' end as ICDTYPE,
            payor.PAYORID  AS VHPAYORID
        FROM
            HI0000001.HI_CLAIMS_SOURCE a
        LEFT JOIN
            HR_745_LOA_SOURCE lvl
        ON
            a.SUBGROUP_NUMBER  = lvl.SUBGROUP_ID
        LEFT JOIN
            HR_745_NWK_CIGNA d
        ON
            a.PROVIDER_REGION_CODE = d.NWKID
        AND
            d.SOURCE = 'SOURCE'
        LEFT JOIN
            HR_745_SPEC_MERGED e
        ON
            a.PROVIDER_SPECIALTY_CODE = e.SRC_SPECCODE
        AND
            e.PAYER='BCBSNC'
        LEFT JOIN
            zzz_procs proc1
        ON
            'I'||REPLACE(a.ICD_PROCEDURE_CODE_1,'.') = proc1.proccode
        LEFT JOIN
            zzz_procs proc2
        ON
            CASE WHEN LENGTH(a.PROCEDURE_CODE)=4 AND SUBSTR(a.PROCEDURE_CODE,1,1)='0' THEN 'R'||SUBSTR(a.PROCEDURE_CODE,-3) ELSE a.PROCEDURE_CODE END = proc2.PROCCODE
        LEFT JOIN
            zzz_procs proc3
        ON
            'D'|| a.AP_DRG = proc3.proccode
        LEFT JOIN
            HR_GLOBAL_PAYORLIST payor
        ON
            payor.TABLENAME = 'HI_CLAIMS_BCBSNC'
        LEFT JOIN
            HR_745_PROVIDER prov
        ON
             'SOURCE' = prov.SOURCE
        AND
             UPPER(COALESCE(a.provider_number,'NULL')) = prov.provid
        AND
            UPPER(Nvl(a.provider_name, 'NULL')) = prov.provname
        WHERE
            a.ENCOUNTER_SERVICE_TYPE_CODE NOT IN ('06','02') AND a.ENCOUNTER_TYPE_CODE <>'CP'
        AND
            REGEXP_REPLACE(a.subgroup_number,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]') IS NOT NULL
        AND
            NVL(lvl.VRSK_EMPLR_GRPID, a.subgroup_number) NOT IN
            (SELECT drp.lvl3id FROM hr_745_lvl3_drop drp WHERE source='BCBSNC')
        AND
        (NVL(lvl.VRSK_EMPLR_GRPID, a.subgroup_number)<>'539431' OR a.CLAIM_PROCESS_DATE<LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2016-09','yyyy-mm')));

        COMMIT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Query Executed: ' || vblqueryName);
        INSERT INTO VH_QUERYLOG(QueryName,CURTIME) VALUES(vblQueryName,SYSDATE);
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
    END;
/
```

Comment: How many indexes do you have on the table? Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu : I dont have any indexes or triggers on this table.

Comment: The first thing to check if it's the inserting that is slow or the query. How long does the SELECT statement on it's own take? What is the execution plan for the statement?

Comment: Does each row have more than 10kB?

Comment: Ten minutes to insert more than five million rows isn't too bad. So how fast do you want it to go? How fast does it go **without** that parallel hint?

Answer (score 1):

Add this statement before the `INSERT`:

```
execute immediate 'alter session enable parallel dml';
```

Remove all the hints and only use this one hint at the top:

```
/*+ APPEND PARALLEL */
```

This allows the entire statement to run in parallel, not just certain parts of the `SELECT`.  Unless you're using an old, unsupported version of Oracle, you normally want to avoid listing the objects in the parallel hint.  Using the parallel hint without a number will hopefully pick a better degree of parallelism, depending on the way the system is setup.  If that doesn't work out, then I'd recommend trying different numbers.  (In short, a higher DOP is always faster, but there are diminishing returns and it can steal resources from other statements.)

After you've done that, take a look at the explain plan for the `INSERT`.  Ensure it's using `LOAD AS SELECT` and not `CONVENTIONAL INSERT` - that's how you tell the statement is using a direct-path write.  The `APPEND` hint is tricky and there are many things that may prevent it from working correctly.

Then run the code and generate a SQL Monitor report like this: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'the insert SQL_ID') from dual;`.  That report will tell you which operation in the query is slow, if any.  The explain plan will probably generate a few dozen lines, and without the SQL Monitor report you'll have to guess which part is slow.  Some of the join conditions look complicated, I wouldn't be surprised if you see a few operations where the estimated rows are 1 but the actual are much higher, leading to NESTED LOOPs instead of HASH JOINs.

Those are high-level hints for getting started with a parallel `INSERT`.  You can easily spend hours on a statement like this.